# Open PDF with Word VBA to SaveAs Text

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, ms-word, office365

I am automating processing of PDF files via VBA, but the problem I cannot seem to resolve is Word helpfully showing a dialog box regarding file conversion. **I am looking for a solution which doesn't require modifying the Registry, as this is not permitted in the work environment**

> Word will now convert your PDF to an editable Word Document...

This dialog does offer a check-box 'Don't show this message again' which works as advertised, but I need the code to be portable across PCs and users

The host application is actually Access, where I have a reference to the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library. I also tried directly in Word with the same issue.

Below is the code I'm using - it does work, other than that Word provides a dialog box which I don't want.

```
    Sub convertPDFtoTextViaWord()
       Const filePath As String = "C:\myfilepath\"
       Dim file As String, fileName As String
       Dim myWord As Word.Application, myDoc As Word.Document
       Set myWord = New Word.Application
       file = Dir(filePath & "*.pdf")
       myWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
       Do While file <> ""
           fileName = Replace(file, "pdf", "txt")
           Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(fileName:=filePath & file, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:="PDF Files")
           myDoc.SaveAs2 filePath & fileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText, Encoding:=1252, lineending:=wdCRLF
           myDoc.Close False
           file = Dir
       Loop
       Set myDoc = Nothing
       Set myWord = Nothing
    End Sub
```

I should note that this code does as intended now that I have selected the 'Don't show this message again' checkbox, but I want to programmatically avoid the need to do this, as I will not always be in a position to perform this manual step

I should also note that I tried running the same code (with a few appropriate modifications) directly in Word with the same result

I added the line `myWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` because this is how I would do it in Excel (where I have far more VBA experience)

I also tried changing `Format:="PDF Files"` to `Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto` (which is the default value for the parameter, anyway) with no change

To reiterate, the code works as desired other than that I can't suppress the dialog box which it seems should be exactly what `ConfirmConversions:=False` supports.

Using Office365 ProPlus

Thanks

Comment: This link might help: [MS Word VBA docx to txt message trap code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793695/ms-word-vba-docx-to-txt-message-trap-code)

Comment: Or maybe this one (if you are willing/permitted to fiddle with the Windows registry): [Open PDF in Word without Conversion Message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57f49b29-58cf-45e5-97cc-985fdd9a8c17/open-pdf-in-word-without-conversion-message?forum=isvvba)

Comment: @Rene - First link seems unrelated, the second link looks very relevant, but I have no way of programmatically interacting with the Windows registry (probably rightly) at work. The lack of other solutions there, though, make me pessimistic about there actually being a solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: I did a test with modified code within Word VBA to convert a specific file, not loop through folder. A Word document opens then saves as a .txt file. No popup. Likely won't make a difference but suggest not declaring a variable name same as function argument keyword (FileName).

Comment: @june7 The problem is specific to opening PDFs in Word - there is no dialog box in Word regarding file conversion when opening a Word document in Word. As I said in my post, the code works as presented, but I need to suppress the dialog box in Word, though I take your point that having a variable with the same name as a function argument should be avoided

Comment: Your question says "I also tried directly in Word with the same issue." I am now testing full procedure in Access. Get "Invalid procedure" error on `file=Dir`. First txt file created. Still no popup.

Comment: It seems my second call to the DIR function to test whether the file has already been converted doesn't work as intended, I will edit the original post to remove this line, good pikc-up

Comment: Now code executes without error and without popup. Cannot replicate issue. I am using Access 2010, not Office 365.

Comment: @June7 Since Word 2010 cannot open PDF files, testing using Office 2010 won't help with the main issue, I think...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop over PDF files and transform them into doc with word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890170/loop-over-pdf-files-and-transform-them-into-doc-with-word), See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435301/c-sharp-word-interop-open-a-pdf-without-the-conversion-prompt

Comment: @CindyMeister - your 'possible duplicate' is entirely unrelated, despite the similarity of tags - that question boils down to "why am I getting an error/ why is there no output from my code?". My code is working, barring the suppression of the file conversion dialog. From my further reading, including some of the links provided, I conclude that this is a bug in the implementation of VBA in Word, and that the solution is to modify the registry, either programmatically or by clicking the 'Don't show this message again' check-mark on the dialog, which achieve the same outcome via different means